# Can I update an sql table row in one shot in Python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have two databases. One is the my master database in SQLite and the other is a remote database that gets updated once in a while. I want to read the remote database and update my master database with the changes. Since I don't know which columns have changed, when there is a difference, I would like to just update the entire row.

Is there a way in Python (using SQLite3) to just update the entire row in one shot?

Here is my database example:

```
.headers on
select * from asset;

id|serial|customer_id|upgrade|
1|J0016209|C0010|false
2|J001631G|C0313|false
3|J001631Z|C001Y|false
4|J001632X|C001Y|false
5|J0016330|C001D|false
6|J0016331|C002Y|false
7|J00163D1|C005Y|false
8|J00163F9|C002Y|false
```

Update with:

```
new_data = [
   {'id':'3', 'serial':'J001631Z', 'customer_id':'C001Y', 'upgrade':'true' }
   {'id':'4', 'serial':'J001632X', 'customer_id':'C001A', 'upgrade':'false'}
   {'id':'7', 'serial':'J00163D1', 'customer_id':'C005Y', 'upgrade':'true' }
   {'id':'8', 'serial':'J0016119', 'customer_id':'C002Y', 'upgrade':'false'}
  ]
```

I want to something like this:

```
for row in new_data:
    val_str = build_value_string(row)  # How do I build this?
    cmd_str = "UPDATE {0} VALUES {1}".format(table_name, val_str)
    my_db.cur.execute(cmd_str)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just copy and replace the entire table?

Comment: I guess that would work. I was worried that the table would be offline longer if I deleted and replaced the entire table while others were accessing it.